# getting error Reverse for image not found in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

i want to display uploaded images in my template file, but i am getting this error `Reverse for 'portfolio/steve-jobs.jpg' not found. 'portfolio/steve-jobs.jpg' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`, my images under `mysite/uploads/portfolio/` folder can anyone please help me how to resolve this error ? here i have uploaded my whole `template.html` code here

```
{% for portfolio_data in portfolio %}
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 mb-4 shuffle-item">
        <div class="position-relative rounded hover-wrapper">
          <img src="{% url  portfolio_data.image %}" alt="portfolio-image" class="img-fluid rounded w-100">
          <div class="hover-overlay">
            <div class="hover-content">
              <a class="btn btn-light btn-sm" href="{{ portfolio_data.url }}" target="_blank">view project</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're passing the image object to the `url` function.

`url` is expecting a url name (as defined in `urls.py`), not an object.

The image object `portfolio_data.image` should have a `url` method, depending on your static files set up.

Try removing the url template tag, and simply doing:

```html
<img src="{{ portfolio_data.image.url }}" alt="portfolio-image" class="img-fluid rounded w-100">
```

The reason for the slightly odd error message is because the image object `portfolio_data.image` has a `__repr__` method that returns the file name. This ends up looking like Django can't find the *path*, but actually it can't find a url with a name of the *object* that has a string representation of the path of the object.

It's woth reading more about [Django's URL reversing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) to understand this more, and remember that `{% url %}` is a template tag that wraps `reverse`.